# as3 - format a timestamp string from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, actionscript-3, string, formatting

I'm receiving a date field from a php file, and I need to format it.
I get this string: "2009-11-12 17:58:13"
I want to convert to "November 12, 2009  5:58:13 pm"

I tried to work with the Date class, but I get stuff like this:
Type Coercion failed: cannot convert "2009-11-12 17:58:13" to Date.

Anyone know of any good utilities for doing this?

Comment: Am I restricted to pure Actionscript? or can we use the Flex API (mx.*)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there is no straightforward solution, you can resort to regex:

```
private function formatDate(str:String):String
{

    var regex:RegExp = /(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)\s(\d+):(\d+):(\d+)/;
    var matches:Object = regex.exec(str);       
    var date:Date = new Date(matches[1], Number(matches[2]) - 1, matches[3], 
        matches[4], matches[5], matches[6]);
    var months:Array = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", 
        "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
    var result:String = months[date.month] + " ";
    result += date.date + ", " + date.fullYear + " ";
    if(date.hours > 12)
        result += (date.hours - 12) + ":" + date.minutes + ":" + 
            date.seconds + " pm";
    else
        result += date.hours + ":" + date.minutes + ":" + date.seconds + " am";
    return result;
}
```

Explanation of the regex `/(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)\s(\d+):(\d+):(\d+)/`

```
// Forward slashes - / - at the beginning and end are delimiters

\d+ /* One or more number of digits. 
     * Ideally it should be \d{n} (\d{4} - 4 digits), 
     * but I'm assuming that the input string would always be 
     * valid and properly formatted
     */

- and : //A literal hyphen/colon 

\s   //A whitespace (use \s+ to skip extra whitespaces)

()  /* Parenthetic groups used to capture a string for using it later
     * The return value of regex.exec is an array whose first element is 
     * the complete matched string and subsequent elements are contents
     * of the parenthetic groups in the order they appear in the regex
     */
```

Comment: For me trying to read regex code is like reading Japanese, but this is exactly what I wanted and it works great.

Comment: This is a simple regex - I've added an explanation. Btw, http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html is a good place to start learning Japanese :)

Answer (score 3):

The built-in `Date` class has a `parse()` that should be able to parse that string into a real `Date` object.  Then you could use the `DateFormatter` to turn it into a nicer string.

See also: [Date parse() method reference](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/Date.html#parse%28%29)

EDIT:  **Darn!** I just noticed that parse() wants a format of `Day Mon DD HH:MM:SS TZD YYYY`

SECOND EDIT, assuming you can use `mx.controls.DateFormatter:`

```
import mx.formatters.DateFormatter;
var fmt:DateFormatter = new DateFormatter()
fmt.formatString = "MMMM D, YYYY L:NN:SS A"; 
var prettyDate:String = fmt.format("2009-11-12 17:58:13");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the date() function to convert it on the PHP side. Check [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) for the formatting rules you can use.

This might get you what you want:

`date("F j, Y g:i:s a", $yourDateString)`

Example: if you run:

`echo date("F j, Y g:i:s a")`

you get:

`November 13, 2009 1:45:19 am`

Comment: Thanks, but I was hoping to do it in AS3. I'm getting a nice associative array from php and would rather not have to go in there and mess with all the row data if possible. I might have to resort to that though.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, instead of changing it at the AS3 or PHP level, how about changing it at the source?  If you have control of the SQL statement, you could use the MySQL `date_format()` function:

```
 select date_format(YOUR_DATE_COLUMN, "%M %d, %Y %l:%i:%s %p") from ...
```

Admittedly it's moving a responsibility of the display toolkit farther down to a different layer, and in doing so might make the SQL or PHP less reusable by other clients, but it also gets the job done.  And in some cases the easy way is how it should be done.

btw, here's my test query and the output from it:

```
select date_format(
              cast("2009-11-12 17:58:13" as datetime), 
              "%M %d, %Y %l:%i:%s %p") 
from dual;
```

Output: `November 12, 2009 5:58:13 PM`

See also: [MySQL date_format() function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

Answer (score 0):

Sure thing when using AS3 to run anything is that at any one time YOU WOULD HAVE TO TINKER. Not so much so as the solution offered by Armagosh though.

To parse full formatted Date strings from a sql database in AS3 all you need do is `toString()` type it with the `Date(sql_date)` method of AS3. Please note that even though you won't be told, `Date(string)`, `Date.parse(string)` and string as Date all work differently. Tinker my friend, Tinker...